# Arduino uno not uploading

Tags: c, arduino, uploading

Uploading sketches to my arduino uno worked fine. Now uploading won't work. I get the following error. Is there a way to reset my board? Using the built-in reset button does not help. Error:

```
Arduino: 1.0.6 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Uno" Binary sketch size: 7,878 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum) avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Please give any information on how to fix or reset the board.

Comment: This question appears to be about the hardware, not about a programming problem. It may better fit on [Arduino.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many reason and you need to try 2 or 3 different operations in order to understand why avrdude is not responding

First, check serial port on Arduino IDE, then check what kind of board you have selected in IDE.

Have you left some connected on pin 0 or 1 of your board? They are serial TX and RX used by FTDI to write the sketch on your Atmega, I don't know why but sometimes if you left something connected there, you could have some problems during upload.

Hope this will help you!